# Expect multiple calls to method

Tags: moq, moq-3

How can I tell Moq to expect multiple calls so I can still use the `MockRepository` to `VerifyAll`, as below?

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _mockThing = _mockRepository.Create<IThing>();

        _sut = new Sut(_mockThing.Object);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _mockRepository.VerifyAll();
    }

    private Mock<IThing> _mockThing;

    private MockRepository _mockRepository;

    [Test]
    public void TestManyCalls(Cell cell)
    {
       _mockThing.SetUp(x => x.DoSomething()).Return(new DoneStatus());
    }
}
```

I know you can do this at verify time, but then I would have to verify everything independently.  Is there a to tell it what to expect, rather than verifying it after the event?

Somthing similar to:

```
_mockThing.SetUp(x => x.DoSomething()).Return(new DoneStatus()).Times(20);
```

Basically, I'd like to set all me expectations at the start of the test rather than having them in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the MockRepository for the moment, I've created a class that inherits from `Mock` to provide the functionality you're after. Firstly, the usage (XUnit syntax):

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var mock = new Mock2<IDependency>();
        var sut = new Sut(mock.Object);
        mock.SetupAndExpect(d => d.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>()),Times.Once).Returns(3);
        mock.SetupAndExpect(d => d.DoSomethingNoReturn(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        mock.SetupAndExpect(d => d.DoSomethingNoReturn(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        sut.CallDoSomething();
        mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

The `SetupAndExpect` method is a replacement for `Setup` that allows `Times` to be passed. The `VerifyAllExpectations` is an equivalent to `VerifyAll`. You could fiddle around with these names if you wanted.

The `Mock2` class stores the `expression` and `times` passed to `SetupAndExpect` ready for later use during `VerifyAllExpectations`.

Before I show the `Mock2` code and talk about a `MockRepository` solution, a word of explanation about the wordiness. It was fairly easy to get it working for mocked methods with no return value as the expressions all have a type that is generic over the mocked type. For methods with a return value, however, the underlying verification to be called is `Mock.Verify<TResult>(...)`. In order to be able to bind to the correctly closed method during `VerifyAllExpectations` I ended up using reflection. I'm sure modifying Mock itself to put this functionality in would allow for a less hacky solution.

Now, back to the repository: My thoughts are to modify `Mock2` so that rather than inheriting from `Mock`, it takes an instance of `Mock` as a constructor parameter and uses that to call `Setup` and `Verify`. Then you could write a new extension method on `MockRepository` (`Create2`??) that calls the original `MockRepository.Create` and passes the created `Mock` instance to the constructor of a `Mock2` instance, which it then returns.

A final alternative to this is to add `SetupAndExpect` and `VerifyAllExpectations` as extension methods on `Mock`. However, the storage of the expectation information would then probably have to be in some static state and face clean up issues.

Here's the `Mock2` code:

```cs
public class Mock2<T> : Mock<T> where T:class
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Tuple<Expression,Func<Times>>>> _resultTypeKeyedVerifications =
        new Dictionary<Type, List<Tuple<Expression, Func<Times>>>>();

    private readonly List<Tuple<Expression<Action<T>>, Func<Times>>> _noReturnTypeVerifications = 
        new List<Tuple<Expression<Action<T>>, Func<Times>>>();

    public ISetup<T, TResult> SetupAndExpect<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression, Func<Times> times)
    {
        // Store the expression for verifying in VerifyAllExpectations
        var verificationsForType = GetVerificationsForType(typeof(TResult));
        verificationsForType.Add(new Tuple<Expression, Func<Times>>(expression, times));

        // Continue with normal setup
        return Setup(expression);
    }

    public ISetup<T> SetupAndExpect(Expression<Action<T>> expression, Func<Times> times)
    {
        _noReturnTypeVerifications.Add(new Tuple<Expression<Action<T>>, Func<Times>>(expression, times));
        return Setup(expression);
    }

    private List<Tuple<Expression, Func<Times>>> GetVerificationsForType(Type type)
    {
        // Simply gets a list of verification info for a particular return type,
        // creating it and putting it in the dictionary if it doesn't exist.
        if (!_resultTypeKeyedVerifications.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var verificationsForType = new List<Tuple<Expression, Func<Times>>>();
            _resultTypeKeyedVerifications.Add(type, verificationsForType);
        }
        return _resultTypeKeyedVerifications[type];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this instead of VerifyAll for setups perfomed using SetupAndRespect
    /// </summary>
    public void VerifyAllExpectations()
    {
        VerifyAllWithoutReturnType();
        VerifyAllWithReturnType();
    }

    private void VerifyAllWithoutReturnType()
    {
        foreach (var noReturnTypeVerification in _noReturnTypeVerifications)
        {
            var expression = noReturnTypeVerification.Item1;
            var times = noReturnTypeVerification.Item2;
            Verify(expression, times);
        }
    }

    private void VerifyAllWithReturnType()
    {
        foreach (var typeAndVerifications in _resultTypeKeyedVerifications)
        {
            var returnType = typeAndVerifications.Key;
            var verifications = typeAndVerifications.Value;

            foreach (var verification in verifications)
            {
                var expression = verification.Item1;
                var times = verification.Item2;

                // Use reflection to find the Verify method that takes an Expression of Func of T, TResult
                var verifyFuncMethod = GetType()
                    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Single(IsVerifyMethodForReturnTypeAndFuncOfTimes)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(returnType);

                // Equivalent to Verify(expression, times)
                verifyFuncMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] {expression, times});
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsVerifyMethodForReturnTypeAndFuncOfTimes(MethodInfo m)
    {
        if (m.Name != "Verify") return false;
        // Look for the single overload with two funcs, which is the one we want
        // as we're looking at verifications for functions, not actions, and the
        // overload we're looking for takes a Func<Times> as the second parameter
        var parameters = m.GetParameters();
        return parameters.Length == 2
               && parameters[0] // expression
                   .ParameterType // Expression
                   .GenericTypeArguments[0] // Func
                   .Name == "Func`2"
               && parameters[1] // times
                   .ParameterType // Func
                   .Name == "Func`1";
    }
}
```

Final warnings: This is only lightly tested and not tested concurrently. It doesn't have an equivalent to the overload of `Verify` that takes `Times` rather than `Func<Times>`. There are probably some better names for the methods and/or reasons why this is all generally a bad idea in the first place.

I hope it's of some use to you or someone!

Comment: Fair play Josh, thank you.  Is it on any internet SCM?  If so I'd liek to follow it.  Cheers.